# Can't get .replaceWith() to work right

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've tried this with .toggle() and the longer form below. If I take out the lines for .replaceWith, it works fine to show and hide #the-form, but with it in... #the-form unhides and #show-form changes properly, but neither work for the next clicks.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#show-form').click(
        function() {
            if (jQuery("#the-form").is(":hidden")) {
                jQuery('#the-form').show('fast');
                jQuery('#show-form').replaceWith('<div id="show-form">Hide Form</div>');
            } else {
                jQuery('#the-form').hide('fast');
                jQuery('#show-form').replaceWith('<div id="show-form">Show Form</div>');
            }
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** Removed backslashes from quotes.

**UPDATE 2** Working version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#show-form').live('click',
    function() {
        if (jQuery("#the-form").is(":hidden")) {
            jQuery('#show-form').html('Hide Form');
            jQuery('#the-form').show('fast');
        } else {
            jQuery('#show-form').html('Show Form');
            jQuery('#the-form').hide('fast');
        }
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not just use the html function? jQuery('#show-form').html('Hide Form'), and vice versa

Comment: Realistically, Jordan has the best answer.

Comment: @Joardan... Just tried your advice and it works! Why don't you move that to an answer so I can credit you properly?

Comment: You don't need a live handler if you use html().  One or the other would work.  Html() works just fine on its own in this example.

Comment: @bozdoz yeah you're right. but you helped him see the benefits of using `live()` which will probably come in handy to him later on.

Comment: @bozdoz Great example of why I love stackoverflow.com... guys like me, who know just enough to be dangerous, can actually learn something beyond what we thought we needed to know... great community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving to answer:

Why not just use the html function? jQuery('#show-form').html('Hide Form'), and vice versa

Answer (score 3):

Remove the backslashes from the double quotes in the div `id` attribute. They don't need to be escaped because the string is already encapsulated by single quotes.

```
jQuery('#show-form').replaceWith('<div id="show-form">Hide Form</div>');
```

Also, move the `replaceWith()`, to the callback function for show and hide.

```
jQuery('#the-form').show('fast', function(e) {
    jQuery('#show-form').replaceWith('<div id="show-form">Hide Form</div>');
});
```

Then you'll have to reattach the click event to #show-form. You can reattach events on the fly using jQuery `live()`. [See about it here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

So, it might just be better to use `html()` instead.

e.g.

```
jQuery('#show-form').html('Hide Form');
```

This way, you're not removing and readding a new DOM element, thus the original onclick event listener remains intact.

Comment: Actually it was failing before adding them... but I'll give it a try in case they are left over from the .toggle() attempts.

Comment: Michael, see my answer.  Tested and works.  +1 to mmmshuddup for the slash comment though.  It isn't needed on single quotes if you use double quotes to designate a string, and vice versa.  :)

Comment: Just tested it without slashes and same problem as described.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a click handler, but you need to be using a live click handler, because you are recreating the entire #show-form element.

This should work:

```
jQuery('#show-form').live('click',
        function() {
            if (jQuery("#the-form").is(":hidden")) {
                jQuery('#show-form').replaceWith('<div id="show-form">Hide Form</div>');
                jQuery('#the-form').show('fast');
            } else {
                jQuery('#show-form').replaceWith('<div id="show-form">Show Form</div>');
                jQuery('#the-form').hide('fast');
            }
    });
```

Live handlers work on dynamically created elements, such as the one that you are recreating.

Comment: Even though it worked when I tried Jordan's answer, I just updated my code and the working code above to include your advice as well. Thanks!